# Top Bar broken on the Tour page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The [Tour Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) on the new MSE is busted for me. The link to /review works, but the various pop-out menus don't. The main multicollider just takes me to https://stackexchange.com/ when I click it, and the inbox, rep listing, and help menus don't do anything. Seems to be a JS error getting thrown up in the console on first loading the page:

[image: An error message in the IE11 JS console]

System Info: Win7, IE11, no toolbars, no add-ons, no userscripts, etc.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting a 404 error page when trying to access that link. I guess some sort of updating going on?

Comment: The animations are all busted too. Someone pulled out a couple of sections without removing (or adding error-handling) to the code that references them.

Comment: @Shog9 Heh, just noticed the lack of the animations myself, and was about to edit that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this late last night - needed some JavaScript love with differing content